# Why does my for loop return a value just once?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
function getValue () {
   console.log(1);
   return 2;
};

for (let  i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {   
   getValue();
}
```

It will print 1 a thousand times, but here it will return just once that two at the end of loop. Why?

Comment: how are you saying it is returning only once

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You do nothing with the return value of `getValue()`; the only thing this loop does is log `1` a thousand times. You haven't told it to do anything else.

Comment: Works 1000 times for me: http://i.imgur.com/uc7WL9I.png

Comment: `console.log(getValue());`

Comment: I want to make the question simple that's why I just return value and not perform any logic.

Comment: @Autif Works 1000 times for me with your code. See http://i.imgur.com/uc7WL9I.png.

Comment: it should print 1000 times and then return 2 but if you want to acutally return the 1 and the 2 induvidually 1000 times, maybe wrap the calling of the function in  a, e.g -  `console.log(getValue());`

Comment: @Autif: If the code in the question doesn't actually demonstrate the problem then perhaps you've simplified *too much*.

Comment: You are telling the script to send console.log(1) 1000 times not console.log(i)

Answer (score 1):

It's not being run once. Most likely what you're seeing is this:

[image]

See the "1000"? That means that "1" was output 1000 times. Your javascript console is simply trying to save you some space. If you change the number to something that's different every time you'll see unique instances of the message:

[image]

If your question is "why does it say '1' 1000 times but only '2' a single time" then the answer is very simple. You're only executing the function but never printing its return value, and therefore you'd see the *last* return value. If you want to print `2` as well, use `console.log( getValue() );`.

"Why would I ever want the result of the last call???"

Because stuff like this is awesome:

[image]

Comment: my question is why 2 just one time and that too  in end and not 10 times like i
as the function is been called that many times

yes it runs 10 times but return value one time

Comment: @Autif Because you're never printing `getValue` - you're only calling it. Why do you want it to print something you're never telling it to print? If you want to print `2` (and not just the last return value) use `console.log( getValue() )`.

Comment: @Autif See his explanation man.

Comment: but why the function is not returning '2'  10 times

Comment: @Autif It **is** returning 2 10 times. You're never printing it. Just because it's not showing it in the console does not mean it's not returning it. `getValue()` = no output - `console.log(getValue())` = many outputs. The only reason your javascript console even shows you "2" is for **your convenience as a developer** - it's never supposed to be used for the user.

Comment: I think unlike others I got you @Autif. Well, your function doesn't print 2, so you will see it only once in console, because this is your browsers behavior. To demonstrate this, try `function a() { return 5 } a(); a(); a()`. It will print 5 only once, for you as a developer, but not for the end-user. But don't worry, function will return `5` 3 times actually, you will just never "use this fact".

Comment: Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

maybe I've got what you mean....

you see 1000's 1, than a 2, and you wonder why you only see one 2?

your function acctually returns 2 for 1000 times, but your code do nothing with it, it's "lost", and the console output your last usable return value, the 1000th 2 of the getValue function.

if you add a new return after the loop, you will not see the 2 and you will see this new return value, like this:

```
function getValue () {
   console.log(1);
   return 2;
};

for (let  i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {   
   getValue();
};
var x=function(){
    return "return value string, that you see only once in the console"}
x();
x();
```

as you can see, we call the x() function twice, but we see the returned string only once in the console.